# Are constexpr functions implicitly static?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, static-functions

If I define a function in my `program.cpp`:

```
constexpr bool isThree(const int number)
{
  return number == 3;
}
```

is that any different from declaring it static?

```
static constexpr bool isThree(const int number)
{
  return number == 3;
}
```

It seems that those should be equivalent, since `constexpr` means the function is inline and therefore not shared among compilation units.

Are `constexpr` global functions implicitly static?

Comment: Your reasoning would imply that `static` and `inline` are the same, which they are not. That's unrelated to the function being `constexpr`, in fact.

Comment: constexpr is a compile time feature, where inline/static are runtime features.

Comment: The meaning of constexpr is more restricted than static. The meaning is that given a particular input value the return value is always the same, and the copiler ought to be able to work it out completely during compilation. A static function simply only has scope within one compilation unit. The returned value could change depending on other variables it accesses.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis how is `inline` a run-time thing? It is a link time thing primarily (ODR - and a possible compile-time *hint*). Run-time the code is already generated and `inline` is long gone/means nothing. `static` also primarily affects linkage/visibility, not run-time behaviour.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`constexpr` functions are implicitly `inline`.

`inline` is a linking feature.  An `inline` function with definitions in different compilation units is not an error; if their definitions vary, your program is ill-formed no diagnostic required, but if they have the same definition then all but one version is discarded and that version is used.

`static`, on a non-method function, is also a linking feature.  A `static` definition is not shared outside of its compilation unit; the compilation unit does not 'advertise' that it has a definition for `isThree`.

`static` on a method function has nothing to do with linking.  In that case, it just means that `this` is not implicitly passed to the function.  A method with/without `this` it doesn't work has differences, but they are mostly unrelated to them being `constexpr`.  Note that in at least [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) a `constexpr` method that doesn't use `this` can still be constant evaluated.  Some versions of [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) make `constexpr` methods implicitly `const`; [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) does not.

`&isThree` in one compilation unit and `&isThree` in another can (and usually do) vary when `static` (barring aggressive ICF, which is a matter for a different question).  When `inline` they may not vary.

`inline` functions *are* shared between compilation units.  Their full definition is also often visible in all compilation units aware of it, so it makes compiler "inlining" (as opposed to the keyword) your code easier.  `static` are not.  `constexpr` functions are implicitly `inline`, but not implicitly `static`.

Note that `constexpr` functions can be evaluated in a runtime context sometimes.  When evaluated in a compile time context, their `inline` vs `static` or linkage state really doesn't matter.

`constexpr` means other things as well, but you wanted to know the difference between two different `constexpr` declarations, and none of those meanings change.

Comment: `static` means different things in different contexts, but you mentioned only one meaning. Answer could be improved by mentioning all. 

Comment: @JesperJuhl Sure, it is possible that `isThree` is declared in a class, so added a paragraph about that.

Answer (score 4):

`constexpr` functions are not implicitly static. They have the same linkage as non-`constexpr` functions:

```
// external linkage
constexpr int f1(int x) { /* ... */ }

// internal linkage
static constexpr int f2(int x) { /* ... */ }

// internal linkage
namespace {
constexpr int f3(int x) { /* ... */ }
}

// no linkage
void enclosing() {
    struct S {
        constexpr int f4(int x) { /* ... */ }        
    };
}
```

When a `constexpr` function has external linkage, it has the same address in all translation units. When it has internal linkage, there is a different copy in each translation unit, and those copies have different addresses. However, I believe the result of *calling* a `constexpr` function should not depend on whether it has internal or external linkage (since `constexpr` functions may not contain static variables).